# MySQL - PHP form to insert values into table?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to add comments to a database using a simple form.  For whatever reason, I can't seem to get the table to update when I use said form.  I'm not getting any errors, it's just that nothing happens when I refresh the table afterwards.  In other words, even after submitting the form, the table still has 0 entries. Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$connection = mysql_connect("server", "username", "password");
if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . $connection->connect_error);
}
// Selecting Database
mysql_select_db("database", $connection) or die(mysql_error());

$name = $_POST['name'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO comments (Name, Title, Comments)
VALUES ('$name', '$title', '$comments')";

mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection

?>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're actually not executing the query.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't ever actually execute your query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO comments (Name, Title, Comments)
VALUES ('$name', '$title', '$comments')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Other things:

1. `if ($connection->connect_error) {` is not valid. You can't use the old mysql API in an OOP fashion. You need to use `mysqli` for that.
2. [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).
3. **You are also wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)**
4. You do *no* error checking. How do you expect to know if there are problems if you don't look for them?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I can't believe I missed that!  I really appreciate your other feedback.  To be honest, I was more interested in getting it working before I went ahead with form validation and error checking.  I"m still trying to learn SQL, so I've been focused on "mysql" but I'll dig into "mysqli" as well if the former is now obsolete.  I sincerely appreciate your help!

Comment: *"You don't ever actually execute your query:"* - Ah, the clincher ;)

Answer (score 0):

(note: please change server, username, and password for your server information)

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    $connection = mysql_connect("server","username","password");
    if (!$connection) {
        die('Connect Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    // Selecting Database
    mysql_select_db("database",$connection) or die(mysql_error());

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (Name,Title,Comments)
    VALUES ('$name', '$title', '$comments')";

    mysql_query($sql);
    mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection

    ?>
```

For security (defense against SQL injection) you can using mysql_real_escape_string function for limit input fields. For example:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$comments = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comments']);
```